# What do we mean when we say T1 is more polymorphic than T2?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, higher-rank-types

I am learning type inference with the paper [Practical type inference for arbitrary-rank types](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/) and I stuck in the very begining. I was basically confused on the concept of *more polymorphic than* relation and therefore cannot continue on.

In its section 3.3, it states:

> An argument is acceptable to a function if its type is more polymorphic than the function’s argument type.

In my understanding, to say `T1` is more polymorphic than `T2` is to say that any instances with type `T2` must satisfy the type `T1`. So by my definition, `forall a. a` is more polymorphic than `Int`. `forall a b. a -> b -> b` is more polymorphic than `forall a. a -> a -> a`.

By my understanding, there is a conflict. Given:

```
f :: (forall a. a) -> Int
k :: (forall a. a -> a)
```

`(f k)` is obviously valid[1]. Then according to the quotation from the article, `forall a. a -> a` should be more polymorphic than `forall a. a`. However, take an example, the literal `1` will satisfy `forall a. a` while obviously it is not a `forall a. a -> a` and therefore by my definition, `forall a. a` should be more polymorphic than `forall a. a -> a`. This is a contradiction to the description in the article about the *more polymorphic than* relation.

I am looking for a clear explanation with examples about what this relation exactly is. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

[1]: As in the comment d8d0d65b3f7cf42 noticed me that `(forall a. a)` is not compatible with `(forall a. a -> a)`. There should be a problem of my understanding. And I noticed `(forall a. a -> Int)` rather can accept an argument with type `(forall a. a -> a)` while `(forall a. a) -> Int` cannot. I don't know why this case acts like that.

Regardless my wrong understanding, I am still expecting a good explanation for what the *more polymorphic than* relation is. Thank you :)

Comment: "obviously valid" - have you tried it? In ghci: `:set -XRankNTypes` and then `(undefined :: (forall a . a) -> Int) ( undefined :: (forall a. a -> a) )`

Comment: @d8d0d65b3f7cf42 oh, it's invalid. But `(undefined :: (forall a. a -> Int)) (undefined :: (forall a. a -> a))` is valid then.

Comment: I believe more polymorphic roughly means that if `T` is more polymorphic than `U`, if `x :: T` and `y :: U`, if we can specialize `y :: A` then we can specialize `x :: A`

Comment: I don't see the OP's problem. Section 3.3 of the cited paper is "Subsumption" and contains examples, as well as a reference to Odersky/Laufer, and the code in the paper's appendix has an implementation of "Subsumption checking".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to OP, `(undefined :: (forall a . a) -> Int) ( undefined :: (forall a. a -> a) )` doesn't typecheck, and indeed, `forall a. a -> a` is not more polymorphic than `forall a. a`, so there is no contradiction here.

On the other hand, `(undefined :: (forall a. a -> Int)) (undefined :: (forall a. a -> a))` typechecks, so `forall a. a -> a` must subsume the `a` in the function type, right? It may seem counter-intuitive, but this is precisely the case. Let me explain.

#### Subsumption and type variables

Subsumption (or alternatively: polymorphic subtyping) means "at least as polymorphic", so it's more an analogue of `<=` rather than `<`. In the corrected OP example, `a` is subsumed by `forall a. a -> a` because *in that context* `a` is a non-rigid type variable, and it can be *unified* with the other type. So, `forall a. a -> a <= typeVar b` is deemed true, while also yielding the constraint `typeVar b = forall a. a -> a` (or possibly a different constraint, depending our choice of type inference system. The actual steps may differ significantly from what I sketch in my examples below).

A simple step-by-step example:

```
-- goal 
(forall a. a -> Int) <= (Int -> Int)
-- instantiate variable on the left hand side with a fresh type variable.
(tvar a' -> Int) <= (Int -> Int)
-- check return type subsumption
Int <= Int -- OK
-- check argument type subsumption
Int <= tvar a' -- OK, add "tvar b = Int" to the set of constraints.
-- Done.
```

In general, if we have `forall a. P <= Q` for some `P` and `Q`, we have to find *some* particular instantiation of `a` that satisfies the subsumption relation. This means that we instantiate `a` with a flexible type variable, and then proceed from there on. In this case, we perform a search for a particular type, and we may refine the type variable as we go on.

On the other hand, if we have `P <= forall a. Q`, then the subsumption must hold for *all possible* instantiations of `a` in the right hand side. In this case, we usually instantiate `a` as a *rigid* (or *skolem*) type variable. A rigid type variable is not really "variable"; rather, it stands for some arbitrary (unknown) fixed type, and we cannot refine it. Example with a rigid variable:

```
-- goal
(forall a. a -> Int) <= (forall b. b -> Int)
-- instantiate variable on the left
(tvar a' -> Int) <= (forall b. b -> Int)
-- instantiate variable on the right
(tvar a' -> Int) <= (skolem b' -> Int)
-- check return types
Int <= Int -- OK
-- check argument types
skolem b' <= tvar a' -- OK, record the "tvar a' = skolem b'" constraint 
-- Done.
```

Basically, we can only do two things with skolem variables:

1. We can freely conclude `skolem a <= skolem a`, i. e. they subsume themselves.
2. We can unify them with a flexible variable, i. e. we can have  `skolem a <= tvar b` or `tvar b <= skolem a`.

#### The spin on function types

We have already seen in the examples that `(a -> b) <= (a' -> b')` iff `b <= b'` and `a' <= a`. The `<=` is flipped on the argument types. Why is that?

Suppose our typing context expects some function of type `a -> b`. This function - as functions commonly do - consumes values of type `a` and produces values of types `b`. Somewhat metaphorically, the context has a *demand* for `b`-s, and it is  also able to *supply* `a`-s to our function. If the function returns a type more general than `b`, that's fine, since then it can also satisfy the context's demand for `b`. However, if the function expects a type more general than `a`, the context is bummed. Poor context only has `b`-s on stock, it can specialize them, but cannot generalize them. If only the function was less *picky* about the type it accepts!

According to the jargon, the function type constructor is contravariant (or negative) in the argument type and covariant (or positive) in the return type. There is a nice discussion about variance on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). It's more concerned with subtyping with respect to OOP class hierarchies rather than polymorphic subtyping, but it should provide useful insight on the latter as well.

Let's take a look at an example where the subsumption flip is more salient:

```
-- goal 
((forall a. a -> a) -> Int) <= ((forall a. a -> Int) -> Int)
-- remember: the context can supply "forall a. a -> Int"-s and demands "Int"-s. 
-- check return types
Int <= Int -- OK
-- check argument types
(forall a. a -> Int) <= (forall a. a -> a)
-- instantiate on the left
(tvar a' -> Int) <= (forall a. a -> a)
-- instantiate on the right
(tvar a' -> Int) <= (skolem a'' -> skolem a'')
-- check return types
Int <= skolem a'' -- FAIL: this clearly does not hold.
-- Abort.
```

#### Function type variance in rank-1 versus higher-rank settings

My first two examples had no nested `forall`-s, i. e. they had only rank-1 types. And you may have noticed that the flipped subsumption made no difference whatsoever! Both examples would typecheck just fine if we assumed `(a -> b) <= (a' -> b') iff b <= b' and a <= a'` there, because we only ever had to check subsumption of type variables, skolems and monomorphic types.

So, the covariance-contravariance distinction only becomes relevant with higher-rank types (which is also hinted at in section 3.3 of OP's quoted paper). Although, if I recall correctly the [HMF system](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/132621/hmf.pdf) ignores the function variance spin too, despite being higher-rank.

Comment: _In the corrected OP example, `a` is subsumed by `forall a. a -> a` because in that context `a` is a non-rigid type variable_ - why is no skolemisation necessary in that context `(undefined :: (forall a. a -> Int)) (undefined :: (forall a. a -> a))`? - like it is in your other example, namely `(forall a. a -> Int) <= (forall b. b -> Int)`, where `b` is skolemised.

Comment: @scriptum there the subtyping relation to show is `(forall a. a -> a) <= tvar a'`. There's no `forall` on the right, so there's nothing to Skolemize. Applying the left `undefined` function to a fresh metavariable is performed before trying to check the argument subsumption. Details may differ across algorithms, but this order of doing things is very common.

Comment: This answer was an inspiration to me and helped a lot to comprehend the topic. For that reason I want to share my newly acquired knowledge, so that others can benefit from it as well: [Practical Unification/Subsumption of Higher-Rank Types](https://www.reddit.com/r/functionalprogramming/comments/lp2r61/practical_unificationsubsumption_of_higherrank/)